# Having problem with Tezbox wallet

Tags: tezbox

Wallet disconnects and reconnects. It can not send transaction. I am using latest version.

I am getting message: `"Operation failed. Forge validation error. Local and remote bytes don't match."`

Comment: Tezbox is no longer maintained by its author. Please migrate to an alternative wallet (Kukai, Galleon, Ledger live or others)

Comment: Tezos Stack Exchange is for specific technical questions. Product/wallet support inquiries should be directed at Telegram, Riot, Reddit or the product focused support channels.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with Tezbox. It's no longer fully maintained and you're best to switch.

Cryptonomic Tech, builders of Galleon, have created a pinned reddit post in the Tezos subreddit explaining how to migrate to their wallet if you wish to do so: https://youtu.be/fLnOcezCZU0

Other than that if you'd like to continue on with Tezbox your best bet is to contact Jovan Smith on Twitter (https://twitter.com/JovanTezos) as he's Tezbox's community manager

Comment: Many thanks. The migration option looks good. I'll certainly give it a try.

Comment: Sweet. Mark this as the answer if it does the trick for you please. This will help many people going forward.